# ASP.NET C# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor

Tags: c#, asp.net, soaphttpclientprotocol

**UPDATE** SEND TO VDWWD who close my question.Please pay attention and read my question completly before making your decision. My code exception in 'new x();' initialize constructor? and it not jump inside initialize constructor function. I tried every thing i can, and I'm sure that my problem **is not resolved** in `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it`

I got a big problem with my project. I used SOAP to call SMSBRANDNAME API:

**Controller:**

```
try
{
  string phone = sender.phone;
  string smsContent = sender.smsContent;
  string username = sender.username;
  string password = sender.password;
  string cpCode = sender.cpCode;
  string serviceID = sender.serviceID;
  string commandCode = sender.commandCode;
  BulkApi api = new BulkApi();<<<== **CODE THROW EXCEPTION HERE**
  api.Timeout = 6000;
  result r = api.wsCpMt(username, password, cpCode, "1", phone, phone, serviceID, commandCode, smsContent, "F");

  if (r.result1 == 1)
  {
      return new SMSResult()
      {
          status = "success",
          message = "Gửi tin thành công!",
          errorCode = r.message
      };
  }
  else
  {
      return new SMSResult()
      {
          status = "fail",
          message = "Gửi tin thất bại!",
          errorCode = r.message
      };
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)<<<== **I GOT EXCEPTION HERE**
{
  return new SMSResult()
  {
      status = "error",
      message = "Đã có lỗi xảy ra!",
      errorCode = ex.ToString()
  }; 
}
```

**Function in BulkAPI.cs:**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="CcApiPortBinding", Namespace="http://impl.bulkSms.ws/")]
public class BulkApi : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getIpOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback checkBalanceOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback wsCpMtOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback wsReportHourOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback wsReportDailyOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback wsReportMonthOperationCompleted;

  private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback getFailSubOperationCompleted;


  public BulkApi()
  {               <<<<= **I PUT BREAK POINT HERE BUT CODE NO JUMP IN**
      this.Url = "https://ams.tinnhanthuonghieu.vn:8998/bulkapi?wsdl";
  }

  public event getIpCompletedEventHandler getIpCompleted;


  public event checkBalanceCompletedEventHandler checkBalanceCompleted;


  public event wsCpMtCompletedEventHandler wsCpMtCompleted;

  ............
```

I got this exception:

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(Type type)
>          at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()
>          at BulkApi..ctor() in E:\Project\HtxThienHuong\HTXThienHuong\Services\BulkAPI\BulkApi.cs:line 25
>          at BulkApp.BulkSMS.SendSMS(BulkDto sender) in E:\Project\HtxThienHuong\HTXThienHuong\Services\BulkAPI\BulkSMS.cs:line 47}

**I don't know how to fix it and why it wrong, please save me. Thank you all!**

Comment: My opinion: the code isn't in sync with the binaries you're executing. Clean and rebuild.

Comment: Hi @John, Thank for your support, I worry about that, I tried rebuild many time and this problem still appear. (In C# desktop app working fine).

Comment: please vote to reopen, thank you